iOS location tracking every N minutes
I'm new to iOS development and I'm trying to implement gps tracking in my app that will run every 2 minutes. It worked for me, tracking works, but it only works in the office. As soon as I take the tablet outside and start walking with it, I don't have a single point !!! I only have one point if I open my app during the hike. I've already tried many options but it still doesn't work for me!
Here is an example of my code. All permissions and background processes are included.
class LocationTrackerService: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    static let shared = LocationTrackerService()
    var myLocation: CLLocation? = nil
    var myLastLocation: CLLocation? = nil
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var timer: Timer?
    private var serviceWorks = false
    let employeeMobileTrackerLogDAO = EmployeeMobileTrackerLogDAO()

    private override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.showsBackgroundLocationIndicator = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        UIDevice.current.isBatteryMonitoringEnabled = true
    }

    func startLocationService() {
        let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        if status == .authorizedAlways {
                    serviceWorks = true
                    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
                    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 120, target: self, selector: #selector(checkTrackingSchedule), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
                } else {
                    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
                }
    }
    
    @objc private func checkTrackingSchedule() {
            let currentDateTime = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current
            let hour = calendar.component(.hour, from: currentDateTime)
            let minute = calendar.component(.minute, from: currentDateTime)
            let weekday = calendar.component(.weekday, from: currentDateTime)
            
            if isWithinTrackingHours(hour: hour, minute: minute, weekday: weekday) {
                locationUpdate()
            } else {
                stopLocationUpdate()
            }
        }

        private func isWithinTrackingHours(hour: Int, minute: Int, weekday: Int) -> Bool {
            let isWeekday = (2...6).contains(weekday)
            let isWithinHours = (hour >= 8 && hour < 20) || (hour == 20 && minute == 0)
            return isWeekday && isWithinHours
        }

    @objc private func locationUpdate() {
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func stopLocationUpdate() {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = nil
    }

    func stopLocationService() {
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.delegate = nil
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        serviceWorks = false
    }
    
    func processNewLocation(_ location: CLLocation) {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let latitude: String = String(location.coordinate.latitude).left(num: 10)
        let longitude: String = String(location.coordinate.longitude).left(num: 10)
        
        if let error = employeeMobileTrackerLogDAO.saveLocation(location: location, batteryLevel: Int(UIDevice.current.batteryLevel * 100)) {
            NSLog(error.description)
            error.raise()
        }
        print("\(latitude) : \(longitude) - \(location.horizontalAccuracy) м. (\(formatter.string(from: location.timestamp)))" )
        
        stopLocationUpdate()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        var bestLocation: CLLocation? = nil

        for location in locations {
            let newCoordinates = location.coordinate
            let newAccuracy = location.horizontalAccuracy

            if newAccuracy > 0 && newAccuracy < 100 && newCoordinates.latitude != 0.0 && newCoordinates.longitude != 0.0 {
                if let currentBestLocation = bestLocation {
                    if newAccuracy < currentBestLocation.horizontalAccuracy {
                        bestLocation = location
                    }
                } else {
                    bestLocation = location
                }
            }
        }

        if let bestLocation = bestLocation {
            if self.myLastLocation == nil ||
               (self.myLastLocation!.coordinate.latitude != bestLocation.coordinate.latitude) ||
               (self.myLastLocation!.coordinate.longitude != bestLocation.coordinate.longitude) ||
               (self.myLastLocation!.timestamp != bestLocation.timestamp) {
                self.myLastLocation = bestLocation
                processNewLocation(bestLocation)
            }
        }
    }
}

In my SceneDelegate class
func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        // Called when the scene has moved from an inactive state to an active state.
        // Use this method to restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) when the scene was inactive.
        if (SubjectDTO.shared.gpsTrackerLogging){
            LocationTrackerService.shared.startLocationService()
        } else {
            LocationTrackerService.shared.stopLocationService()
        }
    }

The biggest question for me is why doesn't it work outside?

You can't use a Timer. A Timer will stop running as soon as your app is in the background. You will need "always" location permission with location background mode. This will deliver location updates every second or so. If you only want to record location every two minutes, just keep track of the last time you recorded a location and record a new location if it has been two minutes.

Also, be aware that non-cellular  iPads don't have a gps chip, so their location updates will be limited.

But now the timer is working and I'm testing on an iPad with cellular data.
"If you only want to record location every two minutes, just keep track of the last time you recorded a location and record a new location if it has been two minutes."
Should I be checking in the background as well?

A timer will work in the background when you run under Xcode because the rules are different when your app runs under the debugger.  Every time you get updates in didUpdateLocations you check when you last stored a location. Keep a Date and check its timeIntervalSinceNow if it is <=-120 then it has been two minutes. Store the location and store the new update date.

But in this case, tracking will work constantly and discharge the device very quickly.

Yes. Reporting location every n minutes isn't really a practical idea. I would suggest you look into significant location updates. This uses much less power but only reports location when a significant distance is travelled. If the device isn't moving no updates are reported, but do you really need entries every two minutes saying the device is in the same location?  If you do then there is no other solution.  Core Location doesn't have a method for delivering updates every n minutes

In your processNewLocation(_:) function you are stoping the location updates. The app will likely be closed by the system shortly after, a Timer object cannot keep the app running in the background.
You can check this repository which basically is a simple tracking app:
https://github.com/JFCaBa/TrackingApp

Indeed, the timer on iOS cannot work in the background, so the optimal solution in my case was to use locationManager.distanceFilter = 200.
